# The String after \n is not being displayed at all in the System output

Tags: java, tcp, server, client

So, I'm making a simple Server-client program using TCP as part of my college assignment. I've already created one before using UDP and just have to redo it using TCP. However, I came across something funny while coding. Apparently, Strings I'd send out from the server that contains a \n will only display the part of the String before the \n. All the other substring that follows after \n will not be displayed. I'm sort of puzzled by this. Maybe it might have something to do with my code for sending it?

The code below is from the server side.

P.S. I've tried researching a bit about this, and I couldn't really find anything concerning my issue. I've tried using "%n" because I saw it was suggested in a few forums, but that didn't work.

```
if(clientMessage.equals("1234"))
{
    SendMessage(incoming, "Welcome.\nMenu:\n1. Check balance\n2. Deposit\n3. Withdraw\n4. Quit");
}

public static void SendMessage(Socket incoming, String message){
//9. Initialize String to send to client
//BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String serverMessage;
    try {
        serverMessage = message;
        //10. Initialize PrintStream using getOutputStream() method of 
        //Socket
        PrintStream send = new PrintStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
        //11. Use println() method of PrintSteam to send data to client
        send.println(serverMessage);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ATMTCPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: flush the `PrintStream` when done

Comment: try public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

Comment: You could also create your `PrintStream` with `autoflush` option to ask it ti flush automatically after every `println()` call.

Comment: Could you guys give an example on how to use the autoflush within my code? I've never heard of that hahaha. I tried implementing it to the constructor for my PrintStream by giving the second parameter a "true" value, but it didn't solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I found the mistake I made from a friend of mine who pointed it out. Apparently, the mistake was in the client side. I didn't know that `BufferedReader.readLine()` would only read one line. So, that was why the substring after `\n` wasn't displaying. Afterwards, I came across a few other problems, but with the help of my friend, I eventually solved the problems and finished my assignment. Thank you to everyone who gave their comments!

P.S. I'll post the code of what I did to solve the problem below. The code below is from the client side. I didn't have to change anything on the server side.

```
serverMessage = incoming.readLine();
String[] messages = serverMessage.split("----");
for(int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
    if(choice.equals("2") || choice.equals("3"))
    {
        System.out.print(messages[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(messages[i]);
    }
}
```